# Query multiple tables in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am looking at Azure log analytics for a web app, and I have multiple out-of-the-box "tables" containing data: `traces`, `requests`, `exceptions`, etc.

Can I construct a query that runs on data from multiple tables? I don't want to join data from different sources, I just want to concatenate/interleave it, so I can look for e.g. "all traces *and* exceptions that contain the string 'SQL'".

Notionally, something like:

```
traces, exceptions
| where * contains "SQL"
| order by timestamp desc
| limit 100
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Kusto query to get results in one table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55538434/how-to-write-kusto-query-to-get-results-in-one-table)

Comment: @liam that question is about interleaving results from two queries (which may or may not have the same "table" as a source). This one is about querying data from two tables in a single query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `union`. Something I found very useful is to union all tables with `union *`. For example:

```
union *
| where * contains "SQL"
```

This way you will search in all tables for any column that contains SQL

If you want specific tables (for example `traces` and `exceptions`):

```
traces 
| union exceptions
| where * contains "SQL"
```

[Edit]
There is also a newer command, with the same result (no benefits or cons with the previous one)

```
search in (table1, table2, table3) "SQL"
| where timestamp > ago(6h)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider the `search` operator

```
search in (exceptions, traces) "SQL"
| order by timestamp desc 
| take 100
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/searchoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer